# Adding the current timestamp to the end of file name

Tags: excel, vba

***Background of current VBA code***

At the moment I have the following VBA code, which will select a range of cells from a excel workbook sheet and create a csv of these cells in the directory shown below, where the csv filename is currently "PersonalFinances"

```
Sub CreateNewCSV2()

  Range("A4:AK32").Select
  Selection.Copy
  Workbooks.Add
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Project Files\Personal\PersonalFinances.csv", FileFormat:= _
        xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        
End Sub
```

***My Question:***
How can I modify my above code, so that each day that I run this macro to create the "PersonalFinances" CSV, that I can add the current days timestamp to the end of the CSV filename. So for example, if I ran the macro today, the csv filename would be: "PersonalFinances20210916.csv". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `"C:\Project Files\Personal\PersonalFinances" & Format$(Now, "yyyyMMdd") & ".csv"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update as depicted below:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Project Files\Personal\PersonalFinances" & Format$(Now, "yyyyMMdd") & ".csv",, FileFormat:= _
        xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```